# Re-drawing static cells and giving them a new look IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to costumize the static cells in my storyboard table by drawing them with draw-rect, but how do i loop over all the cells and draw the rect?

I have read this tutorial but it only covers prototype cells:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32283/core-graphics-tutorial-lines-rectangles-and-gradients

Assuming i have a draw rect method, how do i loop the static cells and apply it ?

**EDIT 1:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // START NEW
    if (![cell.backgroundView isKindOfClass:[CostumCellBackground class]]) {
        cell.backgroundView = [[CostumCellBackground alloc] init];
    }

    if (![cell.selectedBackgroundView isKindOfClass:[CostumCellBackground class]]) {
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[CostumCellBackground alloc] init];
    }
    // END NEW

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // NEW

    return cell;
}
```

If i use this in my Table View Controller, this is from the turtorial, i removed the parts that assigned value to the cell, since they are static.

This does not work becouse UITableViewCell has to return a value, and for some reason it does not.

I did assign the ID "Cell" to the rows, as he does in the tutorial

Comment: I think you can use the delegate method willDisplayCell: -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a custom table cell and doing this:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.backgroundView = [[CostumCellBackground alloc] init];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = [[CostumCellBackground alloc] init];
}
```

Then in your tableview controller, since your cells are static, you can assign them as IBOutlets and do something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *returnCell;
    switch(indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0: returnCell = self.staticCell0;
        break;
        case 1: returnCell = self.staticCell1;
        break;
        //etc
    } 
    return returnCell;
}
```

Comment: Will do, sorry for the slow response

Comment: Have you set up your storyboard and created a cell with the identifier of "Cell"? I am modifying my answer to add a suggestion.

Comment: Yes i have, i have created a storyboard with the cell identifier Cell

Comment: The method does get called, but it has to return a cell, and a cell is not returned